# PHP Configuration: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, timezone

Here a weird one. 
I just upgrade to php 5.3.0 and since the upgrade I'm getting the following warning:

> Warning: getdate() [function.getdate]:
>   It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required*
>   to use the date.timezone setting or
>   the date_default_timezone_set()
>   function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still
>   getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/Chicago' for
>   'CST/-6.0/no DST'

After looking in various forums, everybody says that to solve the problem, all you have to do is edit the date zone in the php.ini and restart Apache.

It did not work for me.

I tried

```
date.timezone="America/New_York"

date.timezone=America/New_York

date.timezone="US/Central"
```

Restarted apache after I made the change.

Since I still have the older version of php install, I even made sure that I'm editing the php.ini that the current version of php uses at the time to load

`/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`

Still getting the warning.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Are you editing the correct ini file?

Comment: I found this to be an issue that the timezone was set in the apache php.ini but not the cli php.ini.

Comment: The timezone must be real one, UTC or GMT would not work.

Comment: I resolved removing the comment in the file php.ini. Just remove the ';' before date.timezone!!

Answer (score 37):

Tchalvak, who commented on the original question, hit the nail on the head for me. I've been editing (I use Debian):

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

...which had the correct timezone for me and was the only .ini file being loaded with date.timezone within it, but I was receiving the above error when I ran a script through Bash. I had no idea that I should have been editing:

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

as well. (Well, for me it was 'as well', for you it might be different of course, but I'm going to keep my Apache and CLI versions of php.ini synchronised now).

Comment: +1 OMG, you are a savior!!!!!!!!!!! I symbolic linked the CLI file to the apache ini file. No more of this confusion!

Comment: No problems! Symlinking is probably the best plan to be honest. Happy to have helped. :)

Answer (score 17):

Did you try to set timezone by func:
http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: +1!! Very simple method..

Comment: I m using `Yii`, and encountering the same problem, where to set it in `yii`?

Answer (score 7):

I happened to have to set up Apache & PHP on two laptops recently. After much weeping and gnashing of teeth, I noticed in phpinfo's output that (for whatever reason: not paying attention during PHP install, bad installer) Apache expected php.ini to be somewhere where it wasn't.

Two choices:

1. put it where Apache thinks it should be or
2. point Apache at the true location of your php.ini

... and restart Apache. Timezone settings should be recognized at that point.

Answer (score 6):

Open your .htaccess file , add this line to the file, save, and try again :

```
php_value date.timezone "America/Sao_Paulo"
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 5):

try this, it works for me.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

In the actual file that was complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Check for syntax errors in the php.ini file, specially **before** the Date paramaters, that prevent the file from being parsed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Please modify your index.php as follows:

```
require_once($yii);
$app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);
Yii::app()->setTimeZone('UTC');
$app->run();
```

Comment: Although you answer could solve the problem, making a little comment on how it works won't harm and will make the OP understand better what are you doing.

Comment: In autogenerated code yii created application with information given in config file. In this case at application level we are setting time zone. So we need to create $app instead of writing as

Comment: In autogenerated code yii created application with information given in config file. In this case at application level we are setting time zone. So we need to create $app instead of writing as Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run() as this does not allow us doing any modification to app before running. The change we want to make let app know of our timezone. In future if any other parameter you want to change then you can do so easily by modifying app before running. Hoping it cleared what am I trying to do :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously I'm a little out of season on this question but for the benefit of the next sufferer: I just had this problem and in my case (in contrast to OP who tried the same without success) the fix was to revise *php.ini*, changing

```
date.timezone = America/New York
```

to

```
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

That is adding the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I modified /etc/php.ini

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone =('Asia/kolkata')

and now working fine.

Vipin Pal

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgot to remove the semicolon to uncomment that line. For the `date.timezone = "US/Central"` line, be sure that there's no semicolon in front of that line.

Answer (score 0):

I found, bizarrely, that I could fix the errors by placing the timezone declaration at the TOP of my php.ini file.

It was already in my php.ini. Twice, actually. And I was pulling my hair out because everyone was saying there must be another ini being loaded... There wasn't.

Hope this can save someone else the time/hair loss.

Answer (score -11):

also you can try this

```
date.timezone = <?php date('Y'); ?>
```