# timezone issue in amazon aws ec2 linux hosting

Tags: php, linux, web-services, timezone

I have recently set up my hosting service in amazon aws, From the moment i have started , it keep gives me an error 

`It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in ..`

I have read several posts, All of them are advising to change the php.ini file, I have did that , I have restarted the service several times, But it keep coming,

my php.ini

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions

date.timezone = "Asia/Colombo"

date.default_latitude = 31.7667

date.default_longitude = 35.2333

date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333

Please help me.

-Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Configuration: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213608/php-configuration-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the quotes:

```
date.timezone = Asia/Colombo
```

Comment: I have tried that too. Still same issue. After editing the file, I have restarted the service by executing , sudo service httpd restart

Comment: @DeZéroToxin - I just installed a new server today and got the same error. By simply uncommenting that line and entering the time zone, the problem was solved. Other than that, I don't know. I assume you did delete the semi-colon before the line. Didn't you?

Comment: Yup, i did that. It's exactly looks like in the question, By the way it is the php.ini file in the /etc/ folder right??

Comment: No, it's in the main directory where php.exe is located. Mine is in 'c:\php.'

Comment: I'm talking about the server, there is no php folder in the home man. .:/