# warning in swiftMailer default time zone

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am using swiftMailer and its working fine but after sending mail to my gmail account, I get the following WARNING message :

```
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone 
in /home/jaydeepkanada/public_html/ramienterprise.com/swiftmailerTest/swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/DateHeader.php on line 119
```

Can you please assist me with that message,
Thank you in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Configuration: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213608/php-configuration-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings)

Comment: u can say but i cant resolve and where should i find php.ini in swiftMailer and i also add "php_value date.timezone 'Asia/Kolkata';" but not working...

Comment: it is pointing towards /swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/DateHeader.php on line 119

Comment: The warning will come from the first usage of the `date` function. The location of your `php.ini` file will depend on your operating system and installation details.

Comment: Tom Fenech..this error coming on server,not on local machine i hosted on go daddy server...and switMailer i am using first time...

Comment: thnx for support...i done it...i just add date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); in my DateHeader.php file before the class start...